# Treeset contiene elementos repetidos

Tags: java, ordenamiento

Estoy tratando de guardar una lista ordenada sin elementos repetidos.
He creado un TreeSet, pero veo que inserta elementos repetidos y no veo claro el porqué.
Si utilizo TreeSet.contains() tampoco lo detecta.
Aquí el código

```
TreeSet array = new TreeSet(new Comparator<Integer>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1>o2?o1:o2;
        }
    });
    int valor =0;
    for(int scores_i=0; scores_i < n; scores_i++){

        valor=in.nextInt();
        if (!array.contains(valor)){
            array.add(valor);
        }
    }
```

Los valores que introduzco son 100,100,50,25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La implementación del `Comparator` está mal. Del [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T))

> Returns:
>       a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Como sólo pasas valores positivos, siempre indica que el primer elemento es mayor que el segundo, sean cuales sean los valores.

Una implementación típica para `ints` sería

```
return o2-o1;
```

Si `o1` es menor devuelve un número mayor que 0, si `o1` es mayor devuelve un número negativo, si los dos son iguales devuelve `0`.

Por supuesto, es más sencillo usar el método `compareTo` de `Integer` directamente, ya que `Integer` implementa `Comparable`

```
return o1.compareTo(o2);
```

o directamente crear un `TreeSet` sin `Comparator`, ya que usas el orden definido por `Integer.compareTo` y eso ya lo hace `TreeSet` sin necesidad de más lógica.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

El comparador, debe devolver 1, 0 o -1.

1 si es mayor, 0 si es igual y -1 si es menor.

Tu estas comparando dos números, y despues devuelves uno u otro en función de si es mayor o no, si ambos números son positivos, siempre devolverás > 0 por lo que siempre te dirá que el primero es mayor.

Prueba con algo así:

```
@Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        int flag = 0;
        if(o1>o2){
            flag = 1;
        } else if(o1 == o2){
            flag = 0;
        } else {
            flag = -1;
        }
        return flag;
    }
```